# How to create copy of a 3D list in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have this code

```
list1 = [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
list2 = list1
list1[0][0][0] = 2
print(list2)
```

I want to create a copy of list1 in list2 so that when I change the value in list1 it doesn't change the value in list2 also.

Comment: Try :  `list2 = list1[:]`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, perhaps because it is a 3d list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

```
import copy
list1 = [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
list2 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
list1[0][0][0] = 2
print(list2)
```